# Pass variables to another laravel function

Tags: php, laravel, variables, datatables

Hello I am using laravel Yajra datatables, the matter is that I have a 2 variables created in a function with the name of the id.

This is all the code

```json
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Datatables;

use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;
use App\Reportes;

class ReportesDatatable
{
    public function ReportesDatatable()
    {
        $reportes = Reportes::get();

        return Datatables::of($reportes)
            ->editColumn('reportante', function ($reportes) {
              $reportante = User::find($reportes->reportante);              
              return $reportante->name;             
            })      
            ->editColumn('user_id_afectado', function ($reportes) {
              $nameafectado = User::find($reportes->user_id_afectado);              
              return $nameafectado->name;               
            })      
            ->editColumn('created_at', function ($reportes) {
                return '<span data-popup="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="' . $reportes->timestamp . '">' . $reportes->timestamp . '</span>';
            })
            ->addColumn('action', function ($reportes) {
                return '<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified"> <a href="' . route('admin.get.editUser', $reportes->reportante) . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mr-2"> Ver Reportante</a> <a href="' . route('admin.get.editUser', $reportes->user_id_afectado) . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2">Afectado</a> <a href="' . route('admin.impersonate', $reportes->user_id_afectado) . '" data-popup="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Logear como Afectado ' . $reportes->user_id_afectado . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"> <i class="icon-circle-right2 text-white"></i></a></div>';
            })
            ->rawColumns(['role', 'action', 'created_at'])
            ->make(true);

    }
}
```

The variables that I need to rescue are these.
I do this to no longer query the database again. I think what would be the most optimal?

```
              1.- $reportante = User::find($reportes->reportante);  
              2.- $nameafectado = User::find($reportes->user_id_afectado);
```

I need to rescue those 2 variables and put them in the function

```
            ->addColumn('action', function ($reportes) {
                return '<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified"> <a href="' . route('admin.get.editUser', $reportante) . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mr-2"> Ver Reportante</a> <a href="' . route('admin.get.editUser', $nameafectado) . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2">Afectado</a> <a href="' . route('admin.impersonate', $reportes->user_id_afectado) . '" data-popup="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Logear como Afectado ' . $nameafectado . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"> <i class="icon-circle-right2 text-white"></i></a></div>';
            })
```

The variable would remain in this way with the rescued variables.

Currently if I put the variables they tell me that they do not exist because they are in a different function I think.

How to make those variables global?

Comment: Is the `Reportes` model setup with a relation to the `User` model. If you have a relation, then you can use eager loading. If you can add your `Reportes` model into your question, it may help understand how the relation is.

Comment: "That's why I need to inherit the variable already created in the previous function." - where is the previous function?

Answer (score 2):

In a function closure any external variables are not accessible in the function context, you can include the `use` keyword (Inheriting variables from the parent scope, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-158) to use those variables in a different context

```
public function ReportesDatatable()
{
    $reportes = Reportes::get();
    $reportante = User::find($reportes->reportante);
    $nameafectado = User::find($reportes->user_id_afectado);
    return Datatables::of($reportes)
        ->editColumn('reportante', function ($reportes) use ($reportante) {
          // $reportante = User::find($reportes->reportante);
          return $reportante->name;             
        })      
        ->editColumn('user_id_afectado', function ($reportes) use ($nameafectado) {
          // $nameafectado = User::find($reportes->user_id_afectado);              
          return $nameafectado->name;               
        })      
        ....
}
```

Comment: Yes that way it works, but I don't want to overload the server with too many database queries.
That's why I need to inherit the variable already created in the previous function.

Comment: @NikoBoomer, can you also add the `Reportes` model to the question to see what relations you have on the model, so we can answer this better? Is there a relation for user on the `Reportes` model?

Comment: @NikoBoomer this should work the way you want. I've commented some lines you don't need. The user queries are performed only once when creating `$reportante` and `$nameafectado`. Then you can use them in any internal closures

Answer (score 1):

```
$reportante = User::find($reportes->reportante);
return Datatables::of($reportes)
->editColumn('reportante', function ($reportes) use ($reportante) {
    return $reportante->name;             
})
```

Comment: isn't `$reportes` a collection? `$reportes->reportante` wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes that way it works, but I don't want to overload the server with too many database queries.
That's why I need to inherit the variable already created in the previous function.

Comment: @NikoBoomer i don't if that is a question, but you can use `use` in any function as long as the var you path is in the same context as the fn, so `->addColumn('action', function () use ($reportes, $reportante) {` is also valid

Answer (score 0):

`$reportes` is a collection (`Reportes::get()`) so how is this supposed to work:?

```
->editColumn('reportante', function ($reportes) {
              $reportante = User::find($reportes->reportante);              
              return $reportante->name;             
            })
```

Let's assume you've set up relations of `Reportes` model correctly (hasOne reportante and hasOne afectado(?)), then do this query:
`$reportes = Reportes::with(['reportante', 'afectado'])->get();`

and Datatables:

```
return Datatables::of($reportes)
            //see? single $report, not all $reportes
            ->editColumn('reportante', function ($report) {
              return $report->reportante->name;             
            })
            ->editColumn('user_id_afectado', function ($report) {
              return $report->afectado->name;               
            })
            ->editColumn(....)
```

Comment: Yes that way it works, but I don't want to overload the server with too many database queries. That's why I need to inherit the variable already created in the previous function.